# React: Как добавить pagebreak в компонент во время печати таблицы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, print

Проблема в том что при печати таблица может занимать несколько страниц и в таком случае одна строка текста может делиться по горизонтали и попасть на две страницы, что виглядит не очень красиво.

[image: баг при печати]

Пробую различные настройки медиа принт но результата нет.

Компонент:

```
return (
    < div className="pagebreak">
    {
        row.notes.map((item, i) => (
                    <div className="border-primary" key={i}>
                        {' '}
                        <div className="shutdown-text">
                            {' '}
                            {row.notes[0].message}
                        </div>
                        <div className="user-text">{`${user} ${date}`}</div>
                    </div>
        ))
    }
    </div>
);
```

css:

```
  @media print {
    .pagebreak {
        clear: both;
        page-break-after: always;
    }
  }
```

> Как настроить печать для коректного отображения содержимого с отступами?